# Silhouette plot from dendrogram in R

Tags: r, silhouette

I'm using hierarchical clustering for my data. And I'd like to plot the Silhouette score across different number of cluster. I have searched a lot posts, and I found that I need to use `pam` for the clustering in order to plot the Silhouette score. I'm wodering if there is a way to plot based on hierarchical clustering result?

Here is a sample data:

```
structure(list(safe = c(1.5, 1.5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 
1, 2, 1, 3.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 1, 
1, 1.5, 2.5, 1, 2, 1, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 1, 2.5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 3, 3, 1, 1.5, 2, 1, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 1, 
1.5, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 
1, 2, 1.5, 1, 1), nhood.soccapi = c(1.8, 1.6, 2.8, 2.2, 2, 3.6, 
3.2, 1.8, 1.6, 1.8, 1.4, 3.8, 1.6, 1, 2, 2.2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
2.2, 1, 1.4, 1.8, 2, 2.4, 1.8, 1, 2, 2.2, 1.6, 2.2, 1.2, 2, 2, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1.8, 1.4, 1.6, 1, 2.2, 1.4, 1.6, 2.4, 1.2, 1.4, 
2.4, 2, 2.4, 2, 1.8, 1.6, 1, 1.2, 1.8, 2, 3.4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
1.4, 2, 2.8, 2, 1, 2, 1.2, 1.4, 2, 1.6, 1.4, 2.2, 2.4, 1.8, 1.4, 
1.4, 2, 2.2, 1, 2, 2.2, 1, 1.8, 2.2, 1.6, 1.2, 1, 2, 1, 1.2, 
2.6, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8), DISORDER = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, NA, 2L, 
NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L
), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), Scho_socialdep1000_3 = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, NA, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, NA, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 
1L, NA, NA, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
NA, 2L, NA, 3L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2"), class = "factor")), row.names = 100:200, class = "data.frame")
```

And my cluster code:

```
dist <- daisy(dt, metric = "gower")
cls.env <- hclust(dist, method = "average")
```

Comment: Here are some useful tips for plotting dendrogram: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/beautiful-dendrogram-visualizations-in-r-5-must-known-methods-unsupervised-machine-learning

Comment: By the way: Always try to read the documentation first e.g. using R command `?silhouette`. they have an example for hierarchical clustering as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hclust` returns just a dendrogram representing clusters inside clusters. The silhouette score is defined on one specific clustering and not on all possible clusterings. This is why it works with Partitioning Arround Medoids (PAM) out of the box. In hierarchical clustering, however, one needs to decide first which clustering to chose by cutting dendrogram tree.

This is how to plot the silhouettes for a hierarchical clustering using k=5 clusters:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(cluster)

data <- structure(list(safe = c(
  1.5, 1.5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1.5, 1, 1, 1.5,
  1, 2, 1, 3.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 1,
  1, 1.5, 2.5, 1, 2, 1, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 1, 2.5, 2, 1, 1, 1,
  2, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 3, 3, 1, 1.5, 2, 1, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 1,
  1.5, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1,
  1, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.5,
  1, 2, 1.5, 1, 1
), nhood.soccapi = c(
  1.8, 1.6, 2.8, 2.2, 2, 3.6,
  3.2, 1.8, 1.6, 1.8, 1.4, 3.8, 1.6, 1, 2, 2.2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1,
  2.2, 1, 1.4, 1.8, 2, 2.4, 1.8, 1, 2, 2.2, 1.6, 2.2, 1.2, 2, 2,
  1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1.8, 1.4, 1.6, 1, 2.2, 1.4, 1.6, 2.4, 1.2, 1.4,
  2.4, 2, 2.4, 2, 1.8, 1.6, 1, 1.2, 1.8, 2, 3.4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1,
  1.4, 2, 2.8, 2, 1, 2, 1.2, 1.4, 2, 1.6, 1.4, 2.2, 2.4, 1.8, 1.4,
  1.4, 2, 2.2, 1, 2, 2.2, 1, 1.8, 2.2, 1.6, 1.2, 1, 2, 1, 1.2,
  2.6, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8
), DISORDER = structure(c(
  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
  1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L,
  1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, NA, 2L,
  NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA,
  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L,
  2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L,
  1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L
), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), Scho_socialdep1000_3 = structure(c(
  3L,
  3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, NA, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 1L,
  2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
  1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L, 3L,
  2L, 1L, 1L, NA, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
  2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L,
  1L, NA, NA, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L,
  NA, 2L, NA, 3L
), .Label = c("0", "1", "2"), class = "factor")), row.names = 100:200, class = "data.frame")



dist <- daisy(data, metric = "gover")
#> Warning in daisy(data, metric = "gover"): with mixed variables, metric "gower"
#> is used automatically
dendro <-
  dist %>%
  hclust(method = "average") %>%
  # need to put the elements into mutually exclusive sets of clusters
  cutree(k = 5)

silhouette(dendro, dist) %>%
  plot()
```

Please note that the choice of k is arbitrary. You will get different results selecting another value.

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, Dan. Maybe it's my insufficient understanding of the clustering method. I did have obtained different silhouette score by cutting the tree at different position, and came out the optimized "k". I was trying to figure out an "elbow plot" for that. But from your explaination, because the decision of "cut" is arbitrary, so I can't do this with hierarchical clustering. Maybe I will just manually plot it then.

Comment: The elbow heuristic is a method to justify a given k making it less arbitrary. Quite often, however, there is no clear signal for just one k but many other ks with similar silhouette scores. This depends on the data, of course.